# Unreferenced function inside a namespace

Tags: c++, reference, namespaces, undefined

I  am new at C++ language and I am trying  to understand why the next thing is happening:

I have a header file `header.h`

```
namespace myNamespace{
class myClass{
    public:
        myClass();
        ~myClass();
        void myFunction(void);
}

void myVoid();
}
```

The definitions are in `header.cpp`

```
using namespace myNamespace;

void myClass::myFunction(void){
//DO anything
}

void myVoid(){
//Do anything
}
```

And in the `main.cpp` I have the follow:

```
#include "header.h"

main(){
  myVoid();
  myNamespace::myVoid();
}
```

Why If I try to call `myFunction` of the class `myClass` from the main I have a successful compile, and if I try to call the function as in the main file I have an undefined reference error? I can fix it if in the `header.h` moves `myVoid` out of the namespace.

Why is this happening?  I  am trying to figure out how this works.

Thanks in advice,

Comment: There isn't enough information in `void myVoid(){ }` for the compiler to tell that `myVoid` is supposed to be `myNamespace::myVoid` and not just plain old `myVoid`, so plain old `myVoid` is what goes into the compiled object file and `myNamespace::myVoid` is left unimplemented. Can't find line and verse to back this up, but someone will be along eventually with a standard quote and a real answer.

Comment: What is the compile error and which line? The example doesn't show a call of `myFunction`. The example is inconsistant with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't specify definition of `myVoid` (I mean just declaring it like you did), then the compiler can never be sure if you are implementing the function which is declared in namespace or just defining a new one.

On the other hand, if you are defining `myClass::myFunction`, it has to be the method that is declared in the defined class.

To make it clear, investigate the following code and take a look [here (very similar question)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4084972)

```
namespace Test { 
    int myVoid(void);    // declaration
    class yourClas;      // declaration

    class myClass{       // definition
        public:
            myClass();
            ~myClass();
            void myFunction(void); // declaration which belongs to defined class
    }
}

void myVoid() {  
// definition, but compiler can't be sure this is the function 
// that you mention in the namespace or a new function declaration.  
}

void myClass::myFunction(void){ 
// absolutely definition for the method of the corresponding class 
}
```